# Force unplug SSD without eject and SSD partitions gone

Tags: hard-drive, partition, ssd

I was working copy my photos to my external SSD hard drive from my iPhone. I created a new photo library on SSD(USB connected) and start import from iPhone. But SSD partitions were unmount by itself and showed me an error. So I unplugged the SSD from USB and replug two times and continue import. Last time SSD initializing time extended and I could not wait and unplug the SSD from USB port.

After all this,
When I plug the SSD to USB port again, I am giving "The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer" error.

[image]

[image]

- I tried MiniTool Partition Wizard but it could not find partitions.
- I tried EaseUS Partition Master 12.10 but it could not find.
- I tried Acronis Disk Director 12.5 but it could not find.

The SSD partitions filesystem was NTFS.

How can I get back partitions?

Comment: It rather sounds like the drive was dying & the constant power interruptions have pushed it over the edge. If you could install it internally on any computer, you may at least be able to get some SMART data from it. USB cannot transmit SMART.

Comment: I installed it a windows computer but It could not show partitions. Disk management just show "uninitialized".

Comment: Since NTFS is windows, wouldn’t you want to take that to a windows specific repair tool and / or data recovery tool or service? I’m not sure why we would be the best place to Ask this, but I suppose it’s not off topic if you primarily use the drive with a Mac.

Comment: I used both windows and macos for recover it but I couldn't recover yet. I guessed this is an issue about macos first but I guess this is a partition table issue. But Why macos cause this, I did not understand the reason.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by this. "I was working copy my photos to my external SSD hard drive from my iPhone" How was the ssd connected to your iPhone. Yet when you post an image of disk utility, you are on a mac.  What third party utility were you using to write to the ntfs disk?

Comment: The USB enclosure for your SSD-disk may be failing.  The actual disk may be fine.

Comment: @historystamp I was using a macbook for copy photos from iphone to external ssd. I am using this app for write to the ntfs disk https://osxfuse.github.io/

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen  No, It is not. I tried to plug a windows notebook with sata connection. SSD's Partition table missing.

Comment: The physical disc may be fine even though the data on it is badly mangled. At this point it is probably too late to salvage anything except with forensic power tools

Comment: Also use exfat instead of ntfs for disks shared between Mac and windows.

Comment: I gather that you should not use an external ssd drive for long term photo storage. LoC is still recommending rotational drives for long term document storage.  Apple seems to be saying do not store photos on external ssd drives (sorry no link).  informative video:
http://www.digitalpreservation.gov/multimedia/videos/personalarchiving-photos.html

printed version
http://www.digitalpreservation.gov/personalarchiving/photos.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saved my SSD partitions with [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)

My partition table did gone and My SSD has two partitions, first one is **NTFS** and second one is **mac os extended**.

And I save my partition table like this guide.

https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step#Partition_table_recovery

Comment: I was about to suggest this! Thank you for answering your own question.